# Error to build .apk file of an ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

```
pampa@Pampa:~/Desktop/DemoApp$ ionic cordova platform add android
Platform android created
pampa@Pampa:~/Desktop/DemoApp$ cd platforms/android
pampa@Pampa:~/Desktop/DemoApp/platforms/android$ ionic android --release

[ERROR] Unable to find command: android
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `Ionic CLI` are you using?

Since version `3.0.0` you should add the keyword `cordova` in your cmd if you want to build the `cordova platform`, like

```
 ionic cordova android --prod --release
```

Reference: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md